# Animated view is translated behind oval view

Tags: android, animation, translate

Here is the [current behaviour.](https://streamable.com/pruw5) 
I want the oval view to overlap the animation view. The 'shoulders' need to be hidden inside that oval view.

I'm already using FrameLayout and also tried to bringChildToFront, use translation, elevation but nothing seems to work.

If you need more details to have a bigger picture of the problem please let me know.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/id_face" />

<a.b.c.OvalAnimationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Draw logic:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
        if (horizontalMargin == 0) {
            horizontalMargin = getMeasuredWidth() / WIDTH_FACTOR;
        }

        if (verticalMargin == 0) {
            verticalMargin = 0.11f * getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        fullScreenRect = new Rect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        firstArc = new RectF(
                horizontalMargin,
                verticalMargin,
                getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
                getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin);

        secondArc = new RectF(
                horizontalMargin,
                verticalMargin,
                getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
                getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawArc(firstArc, 0, 360, true, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(secondArc,0, 360, true, eraser);
}

public void init(int borderColor) {
    this.horizontalMargin = 0;
    this.verticalMargin = 0;

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(35);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    eraser = new Paint();
    eraser.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    eraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
    eraser.setAntiAlias(true);
}
```

Animation:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - lLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setDuration(2500);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1]);
    animSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.70f, 1.0f, 0.70f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .4f);
    animSet.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    animSet.setZAdjustment(-1);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            iFaceListener.onFaceAnimationFinished();
        }
    }, animSet.getDuration());
    view.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for - "Here is the current behaviour. I want the oval view to overlap the animation view" - this already seems to be true (red oval overlaps animated person)

Comment: I want the red oval to fully overlap the animated person just like in this picture: https://imgur.com/a/atN5M .I don't want the shoulders to come off the oval. The interior of the oval view should be transparent and the rest of the screen to be fully opaque so that the animated person could 'stay' behind the black fullscreen view. Only the oval view should be visible

Comment: So you want to clip the animation. In your current behaviour you don't have the black overlay. So you want to add that?

Comment: Exactly, i want to clip the animation. I've added in code the semi-transparent full black view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by myself.

Code for posteriority:

```
public class OvalAnimationView extends View {

private Paint transparentPaint = new Paint();
private Paint tPaint = new Paint();
private Paint eraser = new Paint();
private Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
private float horizontalMargin;
private float verticalMargin;
private Canvas temp;

private float WIDTH_FACTOR = 15f;

private Rect fullScreenRect;
private RectF firstArc, secondArc;

private Bitmap bitmap;

public OvalAnimationView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OvalAnimationView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public OvalAnimationView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
        if (horizontalMargin == 0) {
            horizontalMargin = getMeasuredWidth() / WIDTH_FACTOR;
        }

        if (verticalMargin == 0) {
            verticalMargin = 0.11f * getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        fullScreenRect = new Rect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        firstArc = new RectF(
                horizontalMargin,
                verticalMargin,
                getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
                getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin);

        secondArc = new RectF(
                horizontalMargin,
                verticalMargin,
                getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
                getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public void init(int borderColor) {
    this.horizontalMargin = 0;
    this.verticalMargin = 0;

    temp = new Canvas();

    transparentPaint = new Paint();
    transparentPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    transparentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(35);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    if (bitmap == null) {
        createWindowFrame();
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}


protected void createWindowFrame() {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    osCanvas.drawRect(fullScreenRect, transparentPaint);


    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
    float centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    float centerY = getHeight() / 2;
    float radius = 50;
    osCanvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);
    osCanvas.drawArc(firstArc, 0, 360, true, paint);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    bitmap = null;
}
}
```